# Where can I ask questions regarding Electronics?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I am currently doing some electronics and microcontroller programming, and I have a couple of questions to ask the people here.

Most of the questions are regarding wiring on breadboards and components.

---

On which of the websites (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User) should I ask these particular questions?

Comment: Also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com now too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The site for Electronic *Design* questions is: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ however please note that this does not accept questions about the *usage* of consumer products.

Comment: I asked a question on Electronics which was closed because someone decided it was about "use of electronic devices", although my question was really about how the *design* of the device could allow overheating (of a laptop) and by what electrical mechanism it could have happened. I would like to know which site is appropriate for this question if Electronics is not: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638597/can-a-broken-power-supply-connector-cause-a-laptop-to-overheat

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it's about microcontroller programming you could try Stack Overflow as it is a programming question, but I'm not sure there's much of an audience for that kind of question. You never know until you try though I guess.

Other than that, it doesn't really fit Stack Overflow, Server Fault or Super User.

Comment: Well that's the thing...it's not really about the programming per ce, but mostly about the electronics stuff...wiring, components, soldering and all that

Comment: That definitely doesn't fit anywhere.

Comment: hmm, so i guess this is a feature request then

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a feature request. The topic of conversation is defined by the goal of the site, and this particular question does not fit in any of the current Trilogy sites. I would imagine the only way to be able to handle this is by either stating or expecting a electronics site to come out of [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com) when it is open to the public, and I am pretty confident we will see that fairly early on.

I would suggest you keep an eye on the list of StackExchange available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites). There is no Electronics site listed as yet.

Comment: There is one now : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/